# Process results from two different @wire methods after the @wires are finished

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I have two different `@wire` methods that are calling Apex methods to get different results from two different objects.

After this information has been retrieved by each `@wire` respectively, I'd like to afterwards compare the results and set a few other attributes on the page.

How do I achieve this?  Should I use `connectedCallback()` or `renderedCallback()` or neither?

Is there a better way to do multiple Apex method calls then process them afterwards within the JS when the component loads?

I'm hoping there's a graceful way to accomplish this in LWC without having to chain Promises, or having to handle all of this within a single Apex method call.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Option 1: use wire handlers. Instead of writing an Attribute name, you can write a function, and store the data in attributes, then call a common function when both results are available.

---

## Example

```
attr1;
attr2;
@wire(getAttr1, {})
attr1result({data,error}) {
  if(data) {
    this.attr1 = data;
    if(this.attr1 && this.attr2) {
      this.doProcessing();
    }
  } // ... errors ... //
}
@wire(getAttr2, {})
attr2result({data,error}) {
  if(data) {
    this.attr2 = data;
    if(this.attr1 && this.attr2) {
      this.doProcessing();
    }
  } // ... errors ... //
}
doProcessing() {
  // do something with attr1 and attr2 //
}
```

---

Option 2: Use a promise chain.
When calling them in order, keep in mind that this will cause a minor performance penalty.

---

```
connectedCallback() {
  getAttr1({}).then(result => {
    this.attr1 = result;
    return getAttr2({})
  }).then(result => {
    this.attr2 = result;
  }).finally(()=>this.doProcessing());
}
```

Comment: For option 1 - I'm currently using wire handlers for both to store data in attributes, but where/how do I call that common function right afterwards to leverage all the stored data, with the confidence that the data has already been fetched by both wires?

Comment: @BrianMiller I was mobile, so couldn't really write code (I tried, honest!). Now that I'm back, I edited in what I meant as a code example.

Comment: A brave man - wouldn't have dreamt to code while mobile! Doing a simple `if` check on both properties...totally makes sense, thank you!

Comment: Why not just create third apex method which directly returns the response based on other 2 apex methods? You can pass required parameters to this method itself?

Comment: @salesforce-sas I didn't want to make any assumptions about the data models. For example, they might both be generic methods in different classes, each of which is used in various ways, and this one class happens to need both of them.

Comment: @sfdcfox The difference between option 1 and option 2 is that, option 2 is imperative calling, right?

Comment: @javanoob Basically, yes.

Answer (score 6):

We can chain wire services by using properties that are both dynamic and reactive by using it as $properties and also decorating it with track.

> In the below example I have chained getObjectInfo and
>   getPicklistValues wire services in a manner in which I leverage the
>   data from getObjectInfo  into getPicklistValues

```
import {
    LightningElement,
    api,
    wire,
    track
} from 'lwc';
import {
    getObjectInfo
} from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import {
    getPicklistValues
} from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

export default class PocPicklistFilters extends LightningElement {

    // Flexipage provides recordId and objectApiName
    // to be passed from calling component
    @api objectApiName = 'Account';
    @api picklistField = 'Account.Industry';
    defaultRecordTypeId; //Master  Record Type Id
    @track options = [];


    @wire(getObjectInfo, {
        objectApiName: '$objectApiName'
    })
    wiredObjectInfo({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('ObjectInfo' + JSON.stringify(data));
            this.record = data.recordTypeInfos;
            this.defaultRecordTypeId = data.defaultRecordTypeId;
            this.error = undefined;
        } else if (error) {
            this.error = error;
            this.record = undefined;
        }
    }

    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: '$defaultRecordTypeId',
        fieldApiName: '$picklistField'
    })
    wiredPicklistInfo({
        error,
        data
    }) {
        if (data) {
            console.log('picklist' + JSON.stringify(data.values));
            this.processPicklistRawJSON(data.values);
        } else if (error) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
        }
    }

    processPicklistRawJSON(_rawData) {
        this.options = _rawData.map(row => {
            return {
                label: row.label,
                value: row.value
            };
        });
        console.log('picklistprocessed' + JSON.stringify(this.options));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Promise.All

```
 import { LightningElement, wire,track } from 'lwc';
 import getPricebookInfo from '@salesforce/apex/StoreHandler.getPricebookInfo';
 import getSiteUrlInfo from '@salesforce/apex/StoreHandler.getSiteUrlInfo';

export default class ConfigGeneralSettings extends LightningElement {
   @track pricebookMap;
   @track siteMap;

connectedCallback(){
    Promise.all([getPricebookInfo(), getSiteUrlInfo()]).then((values) =>{
        console.log(values);
        this.pricebookMap = JSON.parse(values[0]);
        this.siteMap = JSON.parse(JSON.parse(values[1]).SiteOptionList);
    });
}
}
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all