# Calling @wire functions sequentially

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

Is there any way to call multiple @wire methods sequentially? As per the documentation, all the wire methods will run asynchronously, but what if I want to execute multiple wire methods sequentially, is there any way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/295726/process-results-from-two-different-wire-methods-after-the-wires-are-finished

Comment: If a wire method provides details used in another wire via a reactive property (a tracked property set when the wire results are obtained and passed as a parameter to the second wire using a $reference) then the second wire will be run when the first wire's result updates the tracked property. You can use this to chain wires together.

Comment: Other than the need to pass results from one wire as inputs to another, there doesn't seem to be a valid use case for delaying wire invocations (it unnecessarily lengthens the time the user must wait for the execution to complete).

Comment: Thank you.. This will help.!!

Answer (score 0):

you can wire is a promise...

Assume the scenario is retrieve Accounts and based on accounts retrieve contacts.

```
import getAccounts from '@salesforce/apex/AccountClass.getAccounts';
import getContacts from '@salesforce/apex/ContactClass.getContacts';
import getCases from '@salesforce/apex/ContactClass.getCases';

@wire(getAccounts)
wiredAccounts({error,data}) {
  if (data) {
      if(data.length > 0) {

        //Logic to get contacts
        getContacts()
            .then(() => {
                //Logic in case of sucessful contact retrival
                // Further chaining can also be done here
                //If another chain is added
                return getCases();
            })
            .then(() => {
                //Logic in case of sucessful case retrival
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                //Logic in case of error in contact retrival
            })
      }

      else {
          //No Account logic
      }
  } else if (error) {
    //Logic in case of error messages
  }
 }
```

Instead of chaining async-await can really work well [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)

Hope this helps!!

Comment: async await is better than the solution here...