# How to set order of execution for getter/setter in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-dom

I need your help. I have 2 setters in my LWC component, where I am setting up input field value for time in one and other I am setting up output format.

But `set value` setter is called first before `set outputFormat` . I want to call first `set outputFormat` then `set value`. in html where it's coming as `@api` I have added first `outputFormat` only.

```
@api get outputFormat() {
    return this._outputFormat;
  }
  set outputFormat(val) {
    this._outputFormat = val;
  }
```

and

```
set value(value) {
    this.setValue(value);
  }
```

Please suggest better way to handle this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most languages, including LWC, you cannot control the order of getters and setters. They can be called in any order, and may even change based on different templates or updates to the runtime engine. I stated in a slightly different [Q&A](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/295727/2984) (this one speaking about controlling the order of wire methods), a possible solution is to set private variables in the controller, and have both methods call one common method once all the data is supplied. That would look like:

```
_outputFormat;
_value;
@api get outputFormat() {
  return this._outputFormat;
}
set outputFormat(val) {
  this._outputFormat = val;
  this.setValue();
}
set value(value) {
  this._value = value;
  this.setValue();
}
setValue() {
  if(this._outputFormat && this._value) {
    // do stuff here // 
  }
}
```

Comment: Personally, certainly used a method called from multiple getters to ensure consistent state across a number of `get` values.

Comment: thanks @sfdcfox for detailed explanation, I tried already and wasn't able to control order.